# Where to download 4K videos?

Tags: video, internet

I would like to experience what 4K or 8K videos looks like, where to download?

Sample videos are enough, no need for full-length videos.

Comment: I'm as curious as the next Super User is, but I believe this is still off-topic for SU.

Answer (score 2):

First off, realize that 4k video is generally 4096 x 2304, which most monitors will not support it directly - even high end consumer 30" displays today only display 2560x1600, and the 15" Apple Retina display is still only 2880x1800.  The video will generally be down-sampled to display properly, similar to the way if you tried to play HD video on a non-HD display.

There's a [sample 4k video](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/13/4K_resolution_sample.ogv) on Wikipedia (make sure to click Full Resolution" to get the 4k file)